# dinoraptzor.org cmd

Tags: cmd, вирусы

Кому-нибудь знаком вирус dinoraptzor.org? Лично мне не первый раз. В первый раз я сумел открыть автозапуск и удалить этот вирус из cmd пару месяцев назад. Этот вирус снова вернулся и открывает браузер с рекламным сайтом при запуске 
моего ПК. Из автозапуска удалял, но после перезаггрузки ПК вирус возвращается снова. Включил его заново в автозапуске , чтобы мой avast antivirus смог увидеть его. Так вот , антивирус игнорирует его и уведомляет, что вирусы не найдены. В первый раз этот вирус был найден этим антивирусом)

Comment: из автозагрузки, не из автозапуска)

Answer (score 0):

Эврика! Я долго парился с этим вирусом, немного подумав я решил данную проблему. При сканировании антивирусом зараженными оказались файлы системы windows. Мой avast не видел этого вируса. Покопавшись на форумах решил последовать советам и установил Dr. web. После долгого сканирования я выяснил, то что написано выше. Все файлы связанные с вирусом были обезврежены. После перезагрузки вирусный сайт с рекламой появился, затем еще раз удалил cmd из автозагрузки после дальнейших включений все прошло удачно.